# store hdfs command output to a shell variable

Tags: shell, hdfs

I am trying to the hdfs command output to a shell variable but am getting error. My script is as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
default=$1
date="";
HDFS_PATH='/data/max_emp_value' (This is a directory)
if $(hadoop fs -test -e $HDFS_PATH/*); then
    date = "`hadoop fs -cat HDFS_PATH/*)`"
else
    date=$default
fi
echo date = ${date}
```

Thanks,
stacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this Work - copy and paste it as is.

```
#!/bin/bash
default=$1
date=""
HDFS_PATH='/data/max_emp_value' #(This is a directory)
if $(hadoop fs -test -e $HDFS_PATH/*)
then
    date="`hadoop fs -cat $HDFS_PATH/*)`"
else
    date=$default
fi
echo "date is ${date}"
```

Why do you want to check all files in a directory? `$HDFS_PATH/*` the `*` refers to all files in a directory. Possibly you are trying to check if the files have arrived - in that case you should have one touch file usually marked as `_success` after the transfer is complete. Otherwise you risk of consuming the data in transit.

Comment: thanks a lot. The error was due to extra space. I have only one file in this directory. each time i am loading the maximum date. so, i am checking for /*

Answer (score 0):

You script has some syntax errors ( line 6:~> unwnated `)`, space between `DATE =`). Also, try to use variable name that is not `bash` command (`date` is bash command):

```
#!/bin/bash
default=$1
DATE=''
HDFS_PATH='/user/cloudera/datefiles'

if $(hadoop fs -test -e ${HDFS_PATH}/*); then
    DATE=`hadoop fs -cat ${HDFS_PATH}/*`
else
    DATE=${default}
fi
echo ${DATE}
```

---

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ./test_3.sh 
08/22/2016
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```